# QML using XMLHttpRequest edit JSON file not working

Tags: javascript, json, qml

I import a JSON file in my program and I need to read & edit it.

(Only use QML not QT)

Reading part works totally fine , but writing part doesn't.

This is I try to use XMLHttpRequest sending my data to a json file(through qml workerScript)

"qrc:/1122test.json" is the json file's URL in my program

```java
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("POST" , "qrc:/1122test.json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log("1122state" , xhr.readyState);
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
//            console.log("1122state" , xhr.readyState);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"email":"test@user.com" , "response":{"name" : "newName"}} ));
    console.log("saveed");

}
```

and my json file example

```json
{
   "email":"hi@user.com" ,
   "response": {
       "name":"tester"
   }
   
}
```

Every time I open terminal cat the json file , it remain same("hi@user.com" didn't change to "test@user.com" and so was name part)

I already changed the json file's authority to 777

Every log in java showed but not show any error code.

This bother me for over a week ,
really appreciate any idea !!!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do I understand correctly that you are using `qrc:` instead of address? how do you think this should work?

Comment: qrc: resources are read-only and a copy of what is in your filesystem before the build. You can't update them at all. You can use it as the origin of this data but you can't store it there. `Settings` is a quick and dirty solution that will probably work for data this small/simple.

Comment: thank you for all your help  , I already try use absolute path instead but didn't work. the real project's json file is a lot bigger . in this question is just a sample example ,

Comment: is there any way I can edit my json file through QML (the file is in the same folder with the project) , i did a lot of searching but most people tallking about edit file through QT , thank again for all your help!